# Add Database variable to search function(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am working on a search project where results should be based on user interest.

I have a database column "favmusic" & "favsport" .

I have declared them as variables in PHP.

Now in the following simple Search code(using HTML & Javascript) ,

I just want to know is it possible to add that database variable to perform search based on taking values from the database variable

Here is my Code :

```
     <input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="width:400px;"/>
     <input type="button" name="searchBtn" id="searchBtn" value="Search"  onclick="searchLink()"/>

     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function searchLink()
     {
     var link1 = document.getElementById("search").value;            
     window.location.href = 'https://www.google.co.in/#q='+$favsport '+$favmusic;
     }
     </script>
```

If you see the JavaScript code you can understand that i have added the columns for performing search in addition to database variable.

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is all code 
suppose you have php array

`<?php $fieldArray=array('fruits','gold','pen');?>`

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = <?php echo jsonencode($fieldArray)?>

$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
</head>
```

Here is input type

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="width:400px;"/>
```

Comment: Do i need to put all this in a single file or 1)fieldarray.php 2)search.html with search button ...can you please help me in that

Comment: hi ,its not working ,i added the search button and tried to search but it didn't work ,can you please help me on that

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery auto complete [Jquery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

put this code

`$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
    });`

Just fetch your fields and create one php array like `$favsport_favmusic=array()`.

Then create javascript array like in above example(open link and click on view source)

```
 ` var availableTags=<?php echo jsonencode($favsport_favmusic);?>;`  .
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: <input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="width:400px;"/>
<input type="button" name="searchBtn" id="searchBtn" value="Search"  onclick="searchLink()"/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function searchLink(){
     var link1 = document.getElementById("search").value;            
     window.location.href = 'https://www.google.co.in/#q='+$favsport '+$favmusic;
     }
     </script>

Comment: as you told me to use like this .i have tried to come up with an answer ,please tell me whether it is correct or not .thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you, you want to get a value from the database and add that to the search query, correct?

You can most definetly do this - try looking up PHP Database connection( https://www.google.dk/search?q=php+database+connection&oq=PHP+Database )

Let me know if you need any further help :-)

UPDATE: To have the variables output to the browser in JS, you would do something like

So the final JS block looks like:

```
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function searchLink()
     {
     var link1 = document.getElementById("search").value;            
     window.location.href = 'https://www.google.co.in/#q= <?php echo $favsport."+".$favmusic ?>';
     }
     </script>
```

Comment: yeah ,you are correct.establishing connection is not a problem.thing is i need to get the value and use it in search query ...can you please check my code ,whether it is correct or what kind changes i need to make to the specific JavaScript query ..

Comment: To add a variable from PHP you need to echo them out: <?php echo $variableName ?> Hope it helps.

Comment: ok .after adding that variable ,how can i pass it to the above search query ..please help me on that ..

Comment: i tried to use search with the code you gave ...but when i click search it searches " <?php echo $favsport." ".$favmusic ?>" directly in google ..and it is not referring db ..

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22833041/2521171 does a much better job :-)

Comment: i used that code too ,when i hit search with a keyword ,the link which follows is  " https://www.google.co.in/#q=+ "  and it does not use db values ..it only displays no results found ,do you able to identify the problem

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is just like HTML when it comes to PHP, so you have to echo your PHP results in the JavaScript code.

```
window.location.href = "https://www.google.co.in/#q=<?php echo urlencode($favmusic.' '.$favsport); ?>"
```

Comment: Good call. Edited the answer.

Comment: you only nee one call - urlencode("$favmusic $favsport");

Comment: window.location.href = "https://www.google.co.in/#q=<?php echo urlencode($favmusic $favsport);  is it correct

Comment: Only one way to find out.. (But you miss a . in between $favmusic and $favsport)

Comment: i used the above code  ,when i hit search with a keyword ,the link which follows is  " https://www.google.co.in/#q=+ "  and it does not use db values ..it only displays no results found ,do you able to identify the problem..connection is perfect though with db

Answer (score 0):

@paicubes ... i had edited this code ..can you please tell me it is correct or not

```
 <?php
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>SearchProject | Home Page<?php echo $websiteName; ?> </title>
  <?php require_once("db-con.php"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="width:400px;"/>
 <input type="button" name="searchBtn" id="searchBtn" value="Search"  onclick="searchLink()"/>
 $( "#search" ).autocomplete({ source: availableTags });
 $favsport_favmusic=array()
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function searchLink()
 {
 var link1 = document.getElementById("search").value;            
 var availableTags=<?php echo jsonencode($favsport_favmusic);?>; 
 }
 </script>
 </body>
 ?>
```

Comment: include jquery these line into head section    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>